# Colorbar ticklabels don't match tick positions

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm plotting a meshgrid with `pyplot.pcolormesh`, and I want to customize the ticklabels on the colorbar. I set a list of tick positions, and provide a list of ticklabels, which should match the tick positions, but I don't know ahead of time which ticks will actually be included, since I don't know the max and the min of the data. The problem is that the first ticklabel I provide is always used at the first visible tick, regardless of whether that is the first tick in my list or not.

Working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
m = plt.pcolormesh(a)
c = plt.colorbar(m)
c.set_ticks(np.arange(11))
c.set_ticklabels(np.arange(11))
plt.savefig('mesh.png')
```

This code produces the image below, and the problem here is that the darkest blue is labled 0, while the value in that cell is actually 1, and similarly all the other labels are shifted by 1.

Is this a bug or a feature, and if it's a feature, how can I make sure the labels will match in an elegant manner? I guess I manage with some tests on the data and trying to figure out which tick will be the first visible and so on, but that doesn't seem very pythonic.

[image: mesh]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a feature, because you are setting the `ticklabels` yourself (with the wrong labels). Its best always trying to avoid setting the `ticklabels` manually, unless there is no other way.

If you remove this line, the labels will show up correctly:

```
c.set_ticklabels(np.arange(11))
```

[image]

To improve readability you could also consider normalizing the colors so they become discrete and match specific integer values. But this only works well if the total amount of colors is limited, like in this example.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cmap = plt.cm.jet

bounds = np.arange(0.5,10.5,1)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

m = ax.pcolormesh(a, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
c = plt.colorbar(m, ticks=bounds-0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I need to change the ticklabels for readability, because I'm showing thickness on a log scale, so I'd like the labels to say 10^-1 mm, 10^-2 mm, etc.But I fixed it by querying the data to find the max and the min, and then only generating those labels that will be used.

Comment: You can also use `Formatters` for ticks, which read the value of the tick and then modify it to the right format. But then you only have to define the format and not the values itself.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html